# how to make multiple foreign keys between two tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2012

I am using sql server management studio and I have two tables, "City" and "Booking". In the booking table, there are two columns, "SourceCity" and "DestinationCity". I want to take two foreign keys from city table to Booking table for the above mentioned columns, but I don't know how to do it. I want to use this all for a stored procedure for adding new bookings as well. please help me out here.

Comment: [Create Foreign Key Relationships - Create a foreign key in an existing table: Using Transact-SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/create-foreign-key-relationships?view=sql-server-ver15#using-transact-sql-1)

Answer (score 3):

I guess, youcan try something like this:

```
ALTER TABLE Booking
   ADD CONSTRAINT FK_BookingSourceCity 
   FOREIGN KEY (SourceCity)
   REFERENCES City (CityName);

ALTER TABLE Booking
   ADD CONSTRAINT FK_BookingDestinationCity 
   FOREIGN KEY (DestinationCity)
   REFERENCES City (CityName);
```

I assume CityName is a primary key in the table City